# How to reference a 2-d array in struct for function usage

Tags: c, embedded, system

I am trying to program a game clone using the LCD screen of a microcontroller development board.  I have decided to use a tile approach as the LCD utilities allow me to place individual pixels.  I have my tiles defined as two dimensional arrays in a seperate header file.  Each entry in the array represents the color of that the pixel at that index [y][x].

```
#define TILE_SIZE 4 \\ px

unsigned short TILE[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE] = {
    { Green, Green, Green, Green },
    { Green, Green, Green, Green },
    { Green, Green, Green, Green },
    { Green, Green, Green, Green } 
};
```

In my main file I have defined a tile struct as follows

```
struct Tile {
    unsigned short width; // width of tile
    unsigned short height; // height of tile
    unsigned short pixels[][TILE_SIZE];
    unsigned short x; // x-coordinate to begin drawing
    unsigned short y; // y-coordinate to begin drawing
};
```

I am not entirely sure how to store the data in the TILE array into the pixels[][] array of the sprite struct.  I believe by reference would be the best to avoid excess memory usage, but I believe you cannot pass 2d arrays by reference.  The tile struct is passed to a `render_sprite` function later in the code which loops through the array and displays each pixel.  I would like this `render_sprite` function to be universal, therefore, I am trying to avoid `render_sprite(unsigned short pixels[][4])`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can pass 2d arrays by address. You can't really pass arrays by value in C unless they are part of a struct getting passed by value. So I'm not sure what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a pointer to your `Tile` structure, like `render_sprite(Tile* tile)`. The struct has all info needed (width and height), to fully describe the size of underlying pixels array.